# How to set new login keyring password

Tags: keyrings

I brought my P.C from a shop here in kochi.I asked them to install ubuntu 13.04.
After i brought system to home I understood that they didnt gave me User password to login.(They had created a user named USER during installation).So i set new password by typing commands in to terminal in recovery mode.(Activated root user and set new password for the USER).but later while using some applications it is asking for login keyring.My new password doesn't. matches the keyring password.Help me